# How to align columns with in a Dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

My data: 62 people have 400 data points, some have 200 (and 200 NaN rows).

```
(Rows = 400, Columns = 62)
```

I have to drop every other value for the individuals that have 400 data points, so that everyone has 200. I have keep the first row (index 0), drop the second (index 1), keep the third row (index 2), and so on. I cannot just drop all the rows with Nan, because then they wouldn't be aligned.

```
    p1   p2   p3   p4
0  0.0  1.0  0.0  1.0
1  2.0  3.0  0.3  0.4
2  4.0  5.0  NaN  NaN
3  6.0  7.0  NaN  NaN
```

Result

```
    p1   p2   p3   p4
0  0.0  1.0  0.0  1.0
1  4.0  5.0  0.3  0.4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**New answer:**

Given the input, we could select the even numbered rows from the columns without NaN, reset its index and concatenate it with the columns with NaNs, after dropping their NaNs:

```
msk = df.isna().any()
pd.concat([df.loc[::2, ~msk].reset_index(drop=True), df.loc[:, msk].dropna()], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
    p1   p2   p3   p4
0  0.0  1.0  0.0  1.0
1  4.0  5.0  0.3  0.4
```

**Old answer:**

IIUC, you have a DataFrame that looks like below:

```
    p1   p2   p3   p4
0  0.0  1.0  0.0  1.0
1  2.0  3.0  NaN  NaN
2  4.0  5.0  4.0  NaN
3  6.0  7.0  NaN  7.0
4  8.0  9.0  8.0  9.0
```

As you noted, if we use `df.dropna()`, we'll remove most of the observations. IIUC, your approach would not get rid of all the NaN values. I propose an alternative approach, one that shifts all non-NaN values up in each column:

```
n = 3 # for your case n=200; this is the number of non-NaN values in columns with NaN
out = (df.stack()
       .groupby(level=1).sample(n)
       .reset_index(name='val')
       .assign(i=lambda x: x.groupby('level_1').cumcount())
       .pivot('i', 'level_1', 'val')
       .reset_index(drop=True).rename_axis(columns=[None]))
```

Output:

```
    p1   p2   p3   p4
0  2.0  3.0  8.0  9.0
1  4.0  5.0  4.0  1.0
2  8.0  1.0  0.0  7.0
```

Comment: The problem with that is that you not aligning each data. As I said above, you have to align the index 0 (400 points) with index 0 (200 points), index 2 (400 points) with index 1 (200 points), and so on. The way you presented is scrambling all the datas. The order is important.

Comment: @Fred Is your aim to get rid of all NaNs or just a DataFrame with 200 rows? Since you say, `dropna` wouldn't work, I assume NaN values aren't in the same rows, right? So if you select the even indexed rows, can you remove all NaNs?

Comment: @Fred could you show on my toy example what the desired output is?

Comment: I wasn't able to show on your toy example because the queue is full, but I put in on the question.

Comment: @Fred If you look at the toy example, there are no 0.3 in `p3` and no 0.4 in `p4`. Please edit it with the correct output.

Comment: The NaNs values are all after 200 for the 200 points data, so you probably couldn't use dropna because then you would be deleting all the rows after 200 for the 400 data points as well.

Comment: @Fred Right, but I don't quite understand what you want to do. You didn't include any reproducible example in your original question, so I mocked up an example but you're giving me output that's not possible given the mock example. So either include an example (with expected output) that's representative of your data or show me your expected output given my mock example.

Comment: I am recreating a new example, the numbers inside it does not matter. The example shows that index 2 for the 400 data points is now index 1, and the rest is deleted.